# Wildfly Swarm jar execution fails on startup

Tags: wildfly-swarm

I am able to create the wildfly swarm jar for my project, but while executing i am getting below error:[using gradle and swarm plugin version 2016.10.0]

```
    2016-11-03 16:02:11,548 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1
-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment-mount-provider: org.jbos
s.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment-mount-provider: Failed
to start service
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceCont
rollerImpl.java:1904)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.vfs.TempFileProvider.create(Lj
ava/lang/String;Ljava/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService;Z)Lorg/jboss/vfs/
TempFileProvider;
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentMountProvider$Factory$Server
DeploymentRepositoryImpl.start(DeploymentMountProvider.java:125)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(Se
rviceControllerImpl.java:1948)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceCont
rollerImpl.java:1881)
... 3 more
```

Comment: Which JDK are you using?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should control the version of TempFileProvider, it can be too new or deprecated.